# Split a list or ordered dates into weeks using linq

Tags: c#, linq, functional-programming

Say I have a list of 5 dates `[Mar 2,Mar 6, Mar 7, Mar 26]` all in the year 2018.
The week start on Saturday and end Sunday.
I want the following result

```
[Mar 2]
[Mar 6, Mar 7]
[Mar 26]
```

How can I do it with LINQ? Or in a functional way.

Comment: What type is the list?  DateTime or String?

Comment: Your second question is hard to understand

Comment: The list is DateTime.

Comment: The second part of your question makes no sense at all.

Comment: I think that is because I inverted the question. It should make more sense now hopefully.

Comment: I think i see what you are trying to do, given `[2, 5, 6, 2, 2, 4]` where those numbers represent days, and a week ordering of `[1,2,3,4,5,6,0]`.... I don think this can be solved, as how do you know  `2, 2, 4` are different months i'e `2` and `2,4`

Comment: You are right, I thought of the second question when I was going through the thought process of solving the first one. The `[2, 5, 6, 2, 2, 4]` represent day of weeks. I don't care about month at that point. I am just looking at the `[2, 5, 6, 2, 2, 4]` as a sequence where order matter. I can solve it iteratively by two loop. One loop through the weeks ordering... then another inside loop for the days of weeks. Each time select and remove the first match. Each time I reach one iteration of the outside loop add a new row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following on `DateTime`

[Calendar.GetWeekOfYear Method (DateTime, CalendarWeekRule, DayOfWeek)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.getweekofyear(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Returns the week of the year that includes the date in the specified
>   DateTime value.
>
> - time
>
>   - Type: `System.DateTime`
>   - A date and time value.
> - rule
>
>   - Type: `System.Globalization.CalendarWeekRule`
>   - An enumeration value that defines a calendar week.
> - firstDayOfWeek
>
>   - Type: `System.DayOfWeek`
>   - An enumeration value that represents the first day of the week.

**Given**

```
List<DateTime> myAwesomeList;
```

**Usage**

```
var result = myAwesomeList.GroupBy(x => 
                    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar
                               .GetWeekOfYear(x.date, 
                                              CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, 
                                              DayOfWeek.Saturday))
                          .Select(grp => grp.ToList())
                          .ToList();
```

**Returns**

```
List<List<DateTime>>
```

Comment: This should work for the first case. I wasn't aware of the GetWeekOfYear method but this is indeed a very elegant way to solve the first problem. I updated the question. Hopefully this make it easier to understand.

Comment: I will create a new question for the generic case.

Answer (score 0):

I want to post this as an iterative answer since I don't want to introduce iterative bias thinking into the question since this might influence the elegant of the answer that I get :) So please don't read this if you understand the question being asked.

Here is a quick and dirty way to solve the problem using an iterative way.

```
var orders = new List<int> { 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3 };
var nums = new List<int> {2, 5, 6, 2, 2, 4};


            var queue = new Queue<int>(nums);
            var results = new List<List<int>>();
            while (queue.Count > 0)
            {
                var subLists = new List<int>();
                foreach (var order in orders)
                {
                    if(order == queue.Peek())
                        subLists.Add(queue.Dequeue());


                    if (queue.Count == 0)
                        break;
                }

                results.Add(subLists);
            }
```

Comment: This is actually a pretty neat solution.