# How to split a list based on the order of another list

Tags: c#, linq, functional-programming

Say I have an arbitrary list  `[2, 5, 6, 2, 2, 4]`

Now given a list, let call it list A `[1,2,3,4,5,6,0].`List A contain all the number in the arbitrary list in a certain order. Now let arrange the first list based on the order of List A. Each new order will become a new list. So the outcome should be

```
[2,5,6]
[2]
[2,4]
```

Another example if the list is splitted based on the order of list B `[4,5,6,0,1,2,3]` then the outcome should be

```
[2]
[5,6,2]
[2]  
[4] <-- the different is that now the (ordered?) list change, the 4 is now belong on the next row.
```

I want to do this in LINQ or a functional way. I have an iterative solution that I posted in my original question please don't read it until you have answered or attempted to answer this question as I don't want to introduce iterative bias thinking into the answer...

[Split a list or ordered dates into weeks using linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49419279/split-a-list-or-ordered-dates-into-weeks-using-linq)

Or see below for the iterative answer

```js
var orders = new List<int> { 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3 };
var nums = new List<int> {2, 5, 6, 2, 2, 4};


        var queue = new Queue<int>(nums);
        var results = new List<List<int>>();
        while (queue.Count > 0)
        {
            var subLists = new List<int>();
            foreach (var order in orders)
            {
                if(order == queue.Peek())
                    subLists.Add(queue.Dequeue());


                if (queue.Count == 0)
                    break;
            }

            results.Add(subLists);
        }
```

Comment: Why not use actual code example for your input?

Comment: Why would the first list in the second example have `{2, 5, 6}` for the first item, when `2` is after `5` and `6` in `listB`? Shouldn't it be `{2}` and then `{5, 6}`?

Comment: Please show your iterative solution code

Comment: var arbitrary = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0 };

            var listA = new Queue<int>(new List<int> { 2, 5, 6, 2, 2, 4 });
            var resultsA = new List<List<int>>();

            while (listA.Count > 0)
                resultsA.Add(arbitrary.Where(o => listA.Count != 0 && o == listA.Peek()).Select(o => listA.Dequeue()).ToList());     // Do you need something like this?

Comment: The answers you're getting aren't in the spirit of functional programming. The question doesn't make sense; you state list A contains the numbers of the arbitrary list, yet that's not the case in your example.

Comment: @Warty which number in the arbitrary list is not in `ListA`?

Comment: @RufusL The iterative code is in the linked question. I made the mistake in my question. I will fix it.

Comment: @firefly No, there is zero code in the linked question. Perhaps you mean in one of the answers to the linked question? (joking here - i see now the code you're talking about in your answer to your question) :p

Comment: easy on this noob here, I haven't been back here for awhile. Couldn't figured out how to link to the answer :) . I figured out how to hide my answer in the question now though!

Comment: I literally only looked at your question originally. You already have a clever solution for this, so my answer will be no help.

Comment: @RufusL You helped pointed out the error in my question. That's very important. I imagine the functional answer will be something like this
first we need to figure out how to get a projection 
from the original list and list A to something like this 

`//--() indicate a match

[ 1 ,(2), 3 , 4 ,(5),(6), 0]
[ 1 ,(2), 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 0]
[ 1 ,(2), 3 ,(4), 5 , 6 , 0]`


or orignal list or list B
`[ 4 , 5 , 6 , 0 , 1 ,(2), 3]
[ 4 ,(5),(6), 0 , 1 ,(2), 3]
[ 4 , 5 , 6 , 0 , 1 ,(2), 3]
[(4), 5 , 6 , 0 , 1 , 2 , 3]`

then after that just apply a filter.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this by walking through the the list you want to split one element at a time.

For each element, find it's index in the list that defines the split order. Compare this to the index of the previous item and, if it's bigger, add it to a temporary list. Otherwise, add the temporary list to the results list and set the temporary list to a new list containing just this item.

Continue looping this way until you have a `List<List<int>>` result.

Code is probably easier to understand:

```
public static List<List<int>> SplitOnList(List<int> toSplit, List<int> splitBy)
{
    // Argument validation omitted (check for null and Lengths are equal)

    var results = new List<List<int>>();
    var singleResult = new List<int> {toSplit[0]};

    var lastIndex = splitBy.IndexOf(toSplit[0]);

    for (int i = 1; i < toSplit.Count; i++)
    {
        var thisItem = toSplit[i];
        var thisIndex = splitBy.IndexOf(thisItem);

        if (thisIndex > lastIndex)
        {
            singleResult.Add(thisItem);
        }
        else
        {
            results.Add(singleResult);
            singleResult = new List<int> { thisItem };
        }

        lastIndex = thisIndex;
    }

    results.Add(singleResult);

    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple just using a for loop :

```
            List<int> orderList = new List<int>(){ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0 };

            List<int> input = new List<int>(){ 2, 5, 6, 2, 2, 4 };

            List<List<int>> output = new List<List<int>>();
            List<int> temp = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < input.Count(); i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    temp = new List<int>();
                    output.Add(temp);
                    temp.Add(input[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (orderList.IndexOf(input[i]) > orderList.IndexOf(input[i - 1]))
                    {
                        temp.Add(input[i]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        temp = new List<int>();
                        output.Add(temp);
                        temp.Add(input[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
```